# Best way to deal with internet connection crash during PHP script execution

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that executes multiples inserts in a MySQL Database with PHP PDO.
User clicks a button and a insert is done.
Button can be clicked one minute later and another insert is done.
This can be done until user cliks on button "End Application".
What to do when internet connection crashes before user clicks "End Application"?
Is it possible to rollback the mysql queries even without internet connection?
Thank you.

Comment: You might want to consider changing your architecture. If those inserts are really part of an atomic transaction, then I would think about saving them in the browser's [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) until they click "End Application" and then send only one request to MySQL with all of the data.

Comment: @JeffPuckett thanks for the answer. Are there any options besides this? I'm asking because for now I need to insert the data in MySQL in real-time. And  all inserts are part of an atomic transaction.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an application that can be ended, then it be started as well, which means that you have at least one additional status of the progress of the user;

I would imagine a table with the various states in which the progress can be

- started
- ended
- deleted (?)

Then you need a table in which you need to watch the progress of the user, the status and the run which this person currently does; as it is not clear what your application looks like it is difficult to give some hints on this.

Nevertheless, with a status and a user and a run you can always recover from a break in the internet connection.

Comment: So in this case I would have to run a Cron to verify inserts that did not progressed until end application, right?

Comment: It depends on your system setup. Maybe .. maybe not. What comes to my mind is the system that Mediawiki uses in order to deal with the cache for instance. It gets generated through clicks or activity. You could store the data locally and once you have an active Internet connection, then you could progress with the inserts. Yet what I think is that you need something that keeps track of the progress of the user in order to track his or her actions correctly. Also, you need to verify the data that had been send and only then you would start to empty some kind of local database or table.